# Gitignore doesn't ignore filename that has same name as parent folder

Tags: gitignore

Folder name is

```
HDWLighting/AUTOSAVE
```

and in the AUTOSAVE folder is a filename called AUTOSAVE.d3p, so the path is

```
HDWLighting/AUTOSAVE/AUTOSAVE.d3p.
```

The .gitignore ignores all files in AUTOSAVE folder except AUTOSAVE.d3p

In my master .gitignore file located in

```
HDWLighting
```

I've tried the following:

```
AUTOSAVE/
AUTOSAVE/*
AUTOSAVE/**
```

I have even put a .gitignore file in the

```
HDWLighting/AUTOSAVE
```

directory which simply has:

```
*/*
```

but this fails to ignore the AUTOSAVE.d3p file as well...

The expected results are to ignore the AUTOSAVE.d3p file but instead I am getting the  message "The binary file has changed" in github desktop.

Comment: [Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_notes): The purpose of gitignore files is to ensure that certain files not tracked by Git remain untracked.
To stop tracking a file that is currently tracked, use `git rm --cached`.

Comment: Hi PetSerAl -- I did run the command **"git rm --cached HDWLighting/AUTOSAVE/"** and this is working. I went and looked at the documentation and I think I added the **AUTOSAVE/** in .gitignore after adding the files to be tracked, so by un-tracking the folder this fixed the problem and the rule works as it should now.. thanks